# How to find out the indentation level in Outline View using Swift

Tags: macos, core-data, swift, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

I am using Swift, Cocoa Bindings and Core Data in an OSX Xcode project to display an outline view which is bound to my entity "Series" and displays the attribute "name", which has a to-many relationship with itself.

I want my users to be able to enter only three levels: one root, a child and another child of that child.

Here is my subclass for Series:

```
@objc(Series)
class Series: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var isLeaf: NSNumber   
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var parent: Series
@NSManaged var subGroups: NSSet
}
```

Effectively when the data is entered and saved, "isLeaf" should be changed to true for the third name entry. In this way, it would be impossible for the user to create a fourth entry.

I added this function to the Series subclass, so I could validate each new name entry:

```
func validateName(ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, 
error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
    if let test = ioValue.memory as? String {
    if test != "" {
    println("Name is \(test)")
    // This is where we need to test for indentation level
    }
    } else {
    }
    return true
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that what I need to do is test for the indentation level of the third entry and if it returns 2, then I need to change isLeaf from false to true.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this in practice. Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

Comment: It would seem better to have the data model handle it, and have isLeaf return true if there is a grandparent.  You are suggesting to have the data model query the view for information about the data model's object graph and then return that information to the controls in the view.

Comment: Thank-you so much. Testing for a grandparent which was also root was exactly how I originally wanted to proceed, but I just couldn't work out how to do it in Swift. The validateName function is the only code I have added, so I guess I have to do the test in the AppDelegate, but I'm at a loss ... could you point me in the right direction, please?